# Getting epoch from active and inactive duration

Tags: web3.js, staking, epoch

After call connection.getStakeActivation(newAccountPubkey);
I receive something like this

```
{ active: 0, inactive: 27717120, state: 'activating' }
```

How convert active and inactive to delegated epoch and deactivated epoch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `getStakeActivation`, you'll have to search through the epochs until you get `activating` and `deactivating` as the state.  The `active` and `inactive` numbers tell you how many lamports were active or inactive stake.

As an easier option, you can get all of the transactions involving the stake account with `getSignaturesForAddress` https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress, and then look for the `DelegateStake` and `DeactivateStake` instructions.